# How many boxes of muffins can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
A baker sells muffins of $5$ types. How many different boxes can be put made with
exactly $15$ muffins?

Note: The order in which the muffins are chosen does not matter. For example a box
with $5$ blue berry muffins and $10$ cranberry muffins is the same as a box with $10$
cranberry muffins and $5$ blue berry.

Answer:

If there were only $2$ types of muffins I claim the answer is $16$. However, there
are $5$ types of the muffins. Now consider this equation:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 15 $$
where $x_1 \geq 0$, $x_2 \geq 0$, $x_3 \geq 0$, $x_4 \geq 0$ and $x_5 \geq 0$.
I claim the number of valid solutions to this equation is the same as the number of
different boxes of muffins. Let $c$ be the number we seek.
\begin{align*}
c &= { 15+5-1 \choose {5-1}} = { 19 \choose 4} \\
c &= \dfrac{ 19(18)(17)(16) }{4(3)(2)} = \dfrac{19(9)(17)(4)}{3} \\
c &= 19(3)(17)(4) \\
c &= 3876
\end{align*}
Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yep, seems like standard stars and bars.

Comment: @Kyky If you could post your comment as an answer then I could accept your answer and close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, $c=\binom{19}{4}$ by stars and bars.

Checking with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=19C4) shows that $\binom{19}{4}=3876$, so your calculation is correct.